# Trigger on same id with redirect.js

Tags: jquery, html, css, redirect

I have code like these

```
<a href="javascript:;" id="linkmasterloc" data-target="master" data-judul="location" data-file="add">
                                        <span> Add </span>
                                    </a>
<a href="javascript:;" id="linkmasterloc" data-target="master" data-judul="location" data-file="list">
                                        <span> List </span>
                                    </a>
```

and i have jquery redirect.js like these

```
$('#linkmasterloc').on('click', function() {
            var judul = $(this).attr('data-judul');
            var urlfile = $(this).attr('data-file');
            var target = $(this).attr('data-target');
            $.redirect(url+target,
            {
                judul: judul,
                file : urlfile
            },
            "POST", "_self");
            return false;
        });
```

But my problem is on first link is working, but the second link didn't do anything. How to make second link get trigger like first link??

Comment: ID, a symbol which uniquely identifies an object or record. So think about, what you did wrong ;)

Comment: ID should be unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have two elements with same id's you can set class of them and handle event with class:

```
<a href="javascript:;" id="linkmasterloc" class="linkmasterloc-class" data-target="master" data-judul="location" data-file="add">
                                        <span> Add </span>
                                    </a>
<a href="javascript:;" id="linkmasterloc2" class="linkmasterloc-class" data-target="master" data-judul="location" data-file="list">
                                        <span> List </span>
                                    </a>
```

JS:

```
$('.linkmasterloc-class').on('click', function() {
            var judul = $(this).attr('data-judul');
            var urlfile = $(this).attr('data-file');
            var target = $(this).attr('data-target');
            $.redirect(url+target,
            {
                judul: judul,
                file : urlfile
            },
            "POST", "_self");
            return false;
        });
```

More [info](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute) about id's.

Comment: Wow, i never think that. And yes it working now. Tq So much